# How can I bake Cannelés more evenely with a big silicon pan?

Tags: baking, oven, pastry, french-cuisine

I purchased this cannelés pan which lets me cooks a whopping 77 mini cannelés at once.

[image: Picture of the pan in its packaging]

I have tried it multiple times, with multiple recipes but no matter what I try, I have this result:

[image: Picture of the result of baking]

The outer ones are overcooked (often on one side only) an the inner ones are undercooked. This is clearly because the pan is too large and the heat isn't being distributed equally, but I'm not sure how I can solve this?

I do not have a convection oven, so this is not an option. I put the pan on a cookie sheet as the molds are too small and become unstable if put on my oven's grid.

Is there a better way to distribute the heat, place it in the oven, or change the baking time/temp to make it more even? I'm willing to buy additional tools to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: How sad.  Do you really need to make that many at once?  Can you get rid of this pan and buy a better-sized one?

Comment: I have normal sized ones, but that size is a lot nicer for me. I'd like to make it work!

Comment: My colleagues who made those compulsively always emphasized long and slow..  maybe you could at least turn the pan a few times during that long process?

Answer (score 4):

It's the cookie sheet that's the problem as it impedes air circulation to the middle of the form. The hot air circulates around the outside but it can't get to the middle, so the outer ones get over-baked and the inner ones under-baked. Changing the baking time or temperature isn't going to help.

As for the solution you have 2 choices (other than a fan oven):

1. Get a supporting pan below that allows air circulation, you can buy mesh sheets instead of cookie sheets
2. Cut the form into pieces. Air can't circulate well to the center of that large sheet, so cut it in half and place them apart. They seem to be made of silicone, so a box cutter will go through it no problem. If you cut carefully you won't lose any of the forms, or you could cut through the middle of a line of them

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what a "mesh sheet" would be called? I couldn't find anything made for cooking...

Comment: Open mesh sheet, roasting wire rack, cooking rack all turn up options. Many cooling racks are oven safe too @Ashamedquestion.